# Phpseclib ssh2_fingerprint equivalent

Tags: php, hash, ssh, sftp, phpseclib

I'm trying to refactor some old code which uses the ssh2_sftp functions to the phpseclib library.

I couldn't, however, find an equivalent for the ssh2_fingerprint function, or rather it's hashing algorithm. You can get the host key from the server but I kinda don't get the hashing right.

Can somebody provide something helpful here?

Original

```
ssh2_fingerprint($connection, SSH2_FINGERPRINT_SHA1 | SSH2_FINGERPRINT_HEX);
```

New code (probably)

```
hash('HOW?', $Net_SFTP->getServerPublicHostKey());
```

Or is this wrong after all?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/phpseclib/libssh2-compatibility-layer does what you're trying to do. Here's it's implementation of `ssh2_fingerprint`:

```
function ssh2_fingerprint($session, $flags = 0)
{
    $hostkey = substr($session->getServerPublicHostKey(), 8);
    $hostkey = ($flags & 1) ? sha1($hostkey) : md5($hostkey);
    return ($flags & 2) ? pack('H*', $hostkey) : strtoupper($hostkey);
}
```